# How to reduce cassandra Tombstones

Tags: cassandra-2.1

When I want to query 10,000 datas from cassandra, I got a timeout. And I saw the system.log, find that reach the max Tombstones. When adjust the value of `tombstone_failure_threshold`, it works.

1. How can I to reduce the Tombstones?
2. When I truncate the table, it will product more Tombstones?
   And I also get the execption:

   > java.io.IOException: Error while read(...): Connection reset by peer
   >   at io.netty.channel.epoll.Native.readAddress(Native Method) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.doReadBytes(EpollSocketChannel.java:675) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollSocketChannel$EpollSocketUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollSocketChannel.java:714) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:326) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:264) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:116) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:137) ~[netty-all-4.0.23.Final.jar:4.0.23.Final]
   >       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_40]